# Change image and textblock foreground on TabItem = IsSelected

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabitem

I have some TabItems, each one containg one image and a textblock. Here is the code:

```
<TabItem.Header>
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="sp" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="img" Source="img0.png"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="Tab1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Green"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="TabItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="img1.png" />
                    <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger SourceName="sp" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="img1.png" />
                    <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to change the image's source and textblock's foreground value when the TabItem is selected. The IsMouseOver behaviour is working properly but the TabItem.IsSelected is not working as expected.
Basically this code is not doing what I'm thinking it should do:

```
<Trigger Property="TabItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
<Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="img1.png" />
<Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
```

Please share your opinion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to reach the `IsSelected` property of the `TabItem` from the `TabItem.Header` and that can't be accomplished with an ordinary `Trigger`. Instead, you need to use a `DataTrigger` so that you can `Bind` to the `IsSelected` property with a `RelativeSource Binding`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=
    {x:Type TabItem}}}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" 
        Value="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/Tulips.jpg" />
    <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
</DataTrigger>
```